# get the content of what is in between the second set of quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started python and I try to print the content between quotes

text in my file:

```
set address "Trust" "45.200.0.0/16" 45.200.0.0 255.255.0.0
set address "Trust" "45.200.1.80/32" 45.200.1.80 255.255.255.255
set address "Trust" "ad.corp" 45.200.1.98 255.255.255.255 "active directory server"
set address "Trust" "Infrasun" 45.200.1.2 255.255.255.255 "DNS/DHCP/all that jazz"
set address "Trust" "NAC Team /16 Subnet" 45.200.0.0 255.255.0.0
set address "Untrust" "207.179.9.4/32" 207.179.9.4 255.255.255.255
set address "Untrust" "Laptop Net" 45.128.0.0 255.255.0.0 "Laptop net for use by team"
set address "Untrust" "VoIP Team Subnet" 45.210.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

i would like to print `"45.200.0.0/16","45.200.1.80/32","ad.corp","Infrasun"...` so not in the first set of quotes but the second.

Here is my code:

```
mon_fichier = open ("conf.cfg","r")
fichier = mon_fichier.read().splitlines()

import re

for ligne in fichier:

    if re.match('set address', ligne):      
        expression = re.compile('(?<=")(?P<value>.*?)(?=")')
        match = expression.search(ligne)
        print match.group('value')
```

I only printed out:

```
Trust
Trust
Trust
Trust
Trust
Untrust
Untrust
Untrust
```

but as I said I need: `"45.200.0.0/16","45.200.1.80/32","ad.corp","Infrasun"...`

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions? You can split the line and then pick the fourth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions here as your file is already well formed:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
   for row in reader:
       print(row[3])
```

If you are learning regular expressions, try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = r'^set address "\w+" "(.*?)".*?$'
>>> re.findall(exp, i, re.M)
['45.200.0.0/16', '45.200.1.80/32', 'ad.corp', 'Infrasun', 'NAC Team /16 Subnet', '207.179.9.4/32', 'Laptop Net', 'VoIP Team Subnet']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for this, just use the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

```
for ligne in fichier:
    print(ligne.split('"')[3])
```

You are splitting each incoming line on the double-quote mark `"`. The fourth matching group is what you're trying to get (remember, Python indexes are 0-based).